# Maven tool to build web application

Tags: java, maven-2

i m using eclipse 3.2.2 as IDE. i want maven code to build and deploy my web application, which is using spring web mvc 2.0.

Comment: Then do it? Please give a real question. If you need to get started with maven take a look at the maven homepage: http://maven.apache.org/

Answer (score 6):

I'll give you one way, the easiest way, to get started (the question is too vague to be more precise). First, to setup a webapp managed by maven and to build it, you'll have to create a project with a packaging of type `war`. The good news is that maven as an archetype for that (a tool to generate a project) so this is actually a very easy step. Just type the following command:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp \
                       -DgroupId=com.stackoverflow.q2220593 \
                       -DartifactId=myfirstwebapp \
                       -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

On Windows, type this command in a command window on a single line without the '`\`' at the end. On *nices, you can paste it as is. Once executed, you'll get a ready to use webapp project structure following Maven's conventions:

```
$ cd myfirstwebapp/
$ tree .
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        |-- resources
        `-- webapp
            |-- WEB-INF
            |   `-- web.xml
            `-- index.jsp
```

If you want to add Java classes directly in the webapp project, create a `src/main/java` directory and put your sources there (test classes go in `src/test/java` and test resources would go in `src/test/resources`). Refer to the [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for an overview of the default layout.

For a Spring project, you would typically have to add the Spring dependencies in the `pom.xml` file and put the application context file in `src/main/resources` (files in this directory are available on the class path and will be copied into `WEB-INF/classes`).

To build the webapp (compile classes, compile tests, execute tests, package the webapp), simply run:

```
$ mvn package
```

This will create a .war in the target directory:

```
$ ls target/
classes  maven-archiver  myfirstwebapp  myfirstwebapp.war  test-classes  war
```

To run the webapp, I suggest to use the [Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/):

```
$ mvn tomcat:run
```

No extra configuration is required for this basic use case. Check [the examples](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/examples/deployment.html) for more advanced use cases.

Another option would be to use the [Jetty Maven Plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) (which is often preferred during development). To do so, add jetty-maven-plugin to your pom.xml definition:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

And execute:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

to start jetty (and have it scan your project files for changes).

The [Cargo Maven Plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) would allow to do similar things in a container agnostic way but it might be a bit harder to setup, at least for advanced use cases. Without more details on what you want to do exactly, I wouldn't recommend it for now.

Answer (score 2):

Set your project up as a war project, see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/index.html
Or you could use a reactor style project with a war module, see http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html.

For deployments you could look at the [cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) plugin

Answer (score 1):

- [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)
- [maven-cargo-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin)